# How to solve an error when we use "about dialog set website" in gtk on windows?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtk2

I use `gtk_about_dialog_set_website(GTK_ABOUT_DIALOG(dialog), "http://www.opencv.org/" );`. But when I clicked on it, I see this errors:

[image]

or

[image]

What ideas on how to solve this error would you suggest? Or on what resource on the internet can I find help?

this is a sample code:

```
GtkWidget *dialog;
dialog = gtk_about_dialog_new();
gtk_about_dialog_set_program_name(GTK_ABOUT_DIALOG(dialog),"Test Name");
gtk_about_dialog_set_version(GTK_ABOUT_DIALOG(dialog), "1.0");
gtk_about_dialog_set_copyright(GTK_ABOUT_DIALOG(dialog),"(C) 2010-2016 Test");
gtk_about_dialog_set_website(GTK_ABOUT_DIALOG(dialog),"http://www.opencv.org/");
gtk_about_dialog_set_website_label(GTK_ABOUT_DIALOG(dialog), "Website");
gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), GTK_WINDOW(window));
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
```

I use `gtk_show_about_dialog` but I have same error:

```
static void refgtk(GtkButton *button, GtkWindow *win)
{
gchar* authors[] = { "Santhosh Kumar ",
    "Sameema ",
    "Karthikeyan ", NULL };
gchar* artists[] = { "Gnanasambantham ",
    "Sakthivel ",
    "Chinnusamy ", NULL };
gchar* comments = { "eccvs is a simple version control system" };
gchar* copyright = { "Copyright (c) Santhosh Kumar, Sameema, Karthikeyan" };
gchar* documenters[] = { "Sameema ",
    "Santhosh Kumar ",
    NULL };
static GdkPixbuf* logo;
gchar* name = "PACKAGE";
gchar* version = "VERSION";
gchar* website = "http://www.gtk.org/";
gchar* website_label = "eccvs website";
const gchar *license = "somestuff";
if (!logo) {
    GError* error = NULL;
    logo = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("E:/Works for Gov Project/DOC/GUI/logogui1/GTK+.png", &error);
    if (error) {
        g_warning("Unable to load eccvs logo: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
    }
}

gtk_show_about_dialog(win,
    "authors", authors, "license", license, "license-type", GTK_LICENSE_CUSTOM,
    "logo", logo, "logo-icon-name", "Logo Icon",
    "program-name", "Chapter 6, Exercise 1",
    "version", "1.0",
    "comments", "This is just an exercise from Chapter 6 of the book I'm reading.",
    "website", "http://www.google.com", "website-label", "Application Homepage",
    "copyright", "(C) 2014 Patrick Meyer",
    "wrap-license", TRUE, NULL);

}
```

Comment: The 2nd image is simple: there's isn't and application that can handle the "http" protocol. That could be a few reasons,mostly because there isn't a default web browser, a software security in a background that prevents the http been use, etc. You shoud try to use the solo gtk_show_about_dialog, to  see if you get the same results.

Comment: @Joel, How to use gtk_show_about_dialog instead of gtk_about_dialog_set_websit??

Comment: @Joel, I use gtk_show_about_dialog instead of gtk_about_dialog_set_websit correctly, but I have same error!!! I edit my question and show my new code

Comment: I don't know man, must be some other stuff in background...btw, how do you get installed your gtk stack?